# Is there an open source tool for finding the flow of a python program?

Tags: python, debugging

Is there some tool that can provide the flow of a python program at a functional level (eg. function A called function B with args1 which in turn called function C with args2). If not, what could be a possible starting point to create it? I thought cProfile might be of some help, but it doesn't give the proper stack trace iirc. Is there a better solution than using pdb and parsing the stack trace and providing the result in a better format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very interesting project to visualize the program flow is [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/)!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of Python visual debuggers that'll do what you want:

- [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) (console visual debugger, open-source)
- [WinPDB](http://winpdb.org/download/) (free, open-source)
- [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (shareware, free trial, cross-platform, *not* open source but probably has the best interface of the three)

Comment: Winpdb isn't Windows-only. In fact, in my experience, it's harder to get it working in Windows than in POSIX.

Comment: Actually, a Community Edition of PyCharm was recently released (last week?), open source under an Apache 2 License.